# convert 16 bit decimal into two 8 bit decimal in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am finding a formula which can convert a 16 bit binary number into two separate decimal number

```
0000000110010000 -> 0x0190
I want the decimal number to be 1 and 144
```

I have 50 columns(say M1 to M50) of binary numbers so need to make a generic formula for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If M1 contains your binary number (as a text string), then use

```
=BIN2DEC(LEFT(M1, 8))
```

to extract the left part

and

```
=BIN2DEC(RIGHT(M1, 8))
```

to extract the right part.

If you want the result in the same cell then use something like

`=BIN2DEC(LEFT(M1, 8)) & "|" & BIN2DEC(RIGHT(M1, 8))`

where the `|` is an arbitrary separator, which you can change or omit to suit personal taste.

Answer (score 2):

are they all exactly 16 characters long? You could do:

```
=BIN2DEC(RIGHT(M1,8))
=BIN2DEC(LEFT(M1,8))
```

Comment: Ha. Great minds think alike. I think you were 5 seconds ahead. Have an upvote.

Comment: @Bathsheba: +1 for self-praise.

Comment: Someone's gotta do it.